# CMOS pin off delay

Tags: microcontroller

My doubt pertains to the turn off and turn on time of microcontroller pins. I am aware that the turn on is quicker than a turn off. I am not sure the reason but I believe it has to do with the gate capacitance. Microcontrollers and such CMOS have pins which are controlled via a MOSFET pair inside the silicon. Now the turning on is done by the upper fet and the turning off by the lower fet. To do either means manipulating the capacitance of the gate. Capacitors charge up quickly while draining takes a little more time. Henceforth the delay in turning off the pin compared to turning on. Is my understanding correct ?

Comment: Your understanding is not correct. Why do you think "Capacitors charge up quickly while draining takes a little more time."?

Comment: i think I understood it wrong. Its the opposite. Discharging is faster as it merely shorts the charge in the capacitor whereas charging takes a time =R*C.
But then my hypothesis will fail vis-a-vis the GPIO control of a microcontroller.

Comment: Concerning the CMOS *topology* (P-MOS at top, N-MOS at bottom) turing on and off is completely symmetrical. Both actions involve chagring/discharging (however you see it). *Resistances* of the transistors may differ however (\$R_{on}\$ of the P-MOS transistor usually is higher).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although most controllers have symmetric turn on and turn off time, this is not always the case. Older CMOS logic (the venerable CD4xxx series for instance) had asymmetric turn on and turn off times.

This difference is due to [semiconductor carrier mobility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_mobility).

A P-channel device uses [holes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_hole) for the channel carrier, whereas a N-channel device uses [electrons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron).

As electrons are in the [Conduction band](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valence_and_conduction_bands) and holes are in the Valence band (same link), electrons have a higher energy level and therefore move faster. This difference in mobility accounts for the asymmetric nature of some CMOS drivers.

Note.
Modern devices use different geometries in P and N channel transistors to achieve symmetric switching and delay times.